# Fancybox overflow is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox 2 and am appending html content to the modal. I turned of scrolling, and now the content that overflows the modal is hidden. Is this a problem with the max-height of the modal? How do I fix this?

My Code:

```
$('.fancybox-open').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    'scrolling'   : 'no',
    'closeBtn' : true,
    afterLoad   : function() {
        this.content.html();
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't have enough context for us to continue. Do you have any HTML or CSS files for `fancybox-2`? We will need to see that code to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

### You have multiple possible reasons this is breaking.

We need more info for a definitive answer, but here are some likely/possible reasons.

**Try a few of these parameters:**

```
$('.fancybox-open').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    'scrolling'   : 'no',

    'height' : 1000,           <--- Try these one at a time
    'autoHeight' : true,       <--- Try these one at a time
    'autoResize' : true,       <--- Try these one at a time
    'fitToView' : true,        <--- Try these one at a time

    'closeBtn' : true,
    afterLoad   : function() {
        this.content.html();
    }
});
```

You can read the full plugin options documented here:

- http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: you could also read the documentation ;)  you are suggesting options that are not valid in v2.x

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs This was from 2.0...? Did I miss something? "What's new - Version 2 is completely rewritten with new features and updated graphics."